# fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2

I have a ubuntu vps I am working on. And I am using the default /var/www/ domain, I am also hosting a SMF forum, None of the Packages are installing and such. I was just wondering what I should chown and chgrp everything so that PHP can modify files in a Apache2 WebServer?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at major security issues with this.  PHP would require shell access to reboot apache which I don't think it can do considering it would run a restart command in the middle of the page execution.  It sounds like you need to look at other alternative.

Comment: Doesnt pertain to my question?

Comment: Ah, I see your question more.  It all depends on your user group structure and things.  Have you tried temporarily modifying the files to chmod 777 to see if your scripts will run.  I'd also check for any errors that might be generated by the installation script.

Comment: Well I came to find out that www-data is the user that apache runs under.